# Java: Is the constructor implicitly called when the JVM runs the main() method?

Tags: java, constructor

Consider the following basic class:

```
public class ConstructorExample {

    public ConstructorExample(){
        System.out.println("Constructor called.");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConstructorExample ce = new ConstructorExample();
    }

}
```

When executing the above code, "Constructor called." is only printed once. Obviously, the constructor is called explicitly when the main method is called.

However, why isn't the constructor called when the JVM loads the class and starts the application initially?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**No** to execute `main()` method `jvm` doesn't construct Object of class, thats why `main()` method is `static`

it is being executed with

```
ConstructorExample ce = new ConstructorExample();
```

to confirm comment out below line

`\\ConstructorExample ce = new ConstructorExample();`

Comment: So constructors are only ever called for non-static instances of a class?

Comment: Constructor are only called when *Object is constructed*.

Comment: please read [this piece from jls](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#41652)

Answer (score 1):

Why would the JVM call the constructor at start ? "main" is a static method and it does not need an instance of ConstructorExample to be created.

Answer (score 1):

Why need to call `main()` method via an object ? Afterall, its a `static` method.
Purpose of `main()` method being `static` is JVM doesn't require to create any object for calling the `main()` method.

So, when the `.class` file is loaded by the JVM, the JVM looks for the `main()` method to run. When it sees one, it starts the program execution. After it, the constructor is called(here, in this case) when the object is being created and hence prints "`Constructor called`" only once.